# Is "$(P \land Q) \to P$" a tautology?

Tags: logic

we recently got the statement that $(P \land Q) \to P$ is a tautology, but i do not get why it is one, since it is wrong for certain cases of P and Q.

Comment: Your statement in the question is different in to the one in the title. Also, you need to add dollar signs on either side of the statement to get the MathJax working.

Comment: You should double-check your notes to make sure you've read the claim correctly.

Answer (score 1):

$P\land Q~\to~P$, also written as $(P\land Q)\to P$, is a tautology.   "If $P$ and $Q$ are both true, then $P$ will be true," is clearly so.

Should either $P$ or $Q$ be false, the implication still holds, because implications are considerer true when their antecedants are false (or their consequents are true).

An implication is only considered false when the consequent can be false while the antecedant is true.   However, $P$ can not be false when both $P$ and $Q$ are true.

Thus *for all possible* values of $P$ and $Q$ the implication, $(P\land Q)\to P$, will be satisfied.   It is a tautology.

---

$P\land (Q\to P)$ is a completely different matter.   It is not the same thing at all, and not a tautology.   Although it can be satisfied, it is clearly false whenever $P$ is false.   It is a contingent statement.

---

Long story short: The placement of the brackets matters.   The rules of operation precedence means "$P$ and $Q$ implies $P$" should be read as $(P\land Q)\to P$.